# AutoIt integration with Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, autoit

I am testing a web based application where on clicking an email ID, a New mail in Lotus Notes should be created.

I am using Protractor to automate my web based tests.

I have previously used AutoIt with Java for such case when they occurred in selenium. But have no idea how to do it with Protracotor.

If you have done it before a hint would be enough.

Comment: Can you post your code? I am using SuperSpawn as suggested but AutoIt code is not getting executed

Comment: @Anil Maurya were you success on this? if yes, could you please let me know the solution. I am unable to figure-out how to run exe file in Protractor. your help is really appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Use spawn to run any external scripts/executables. Follow the link for more details-https://www.npmjs.com/package/superspawn

Comment: Sure! Let me know if you need more help. From your question it looked like you want to try it out yourself first.